# How to find and replace data from one JSON file to another using Python?

Tags: json, python-2.7

JSON file contains below data and structure is same across all files, but data under profile will be changing quite frequently.

So, am trying for Python script which will copy and replace entire data under "Profile" node to another JSON files (As Config data is static as each machine has diff static values).

Algo:

Pharse JSON file
Read and extract Profile data
Pharse and replace Entire Profile data to another JSON file

```
{
"config": 
[
    { 
        "Name":"FW",
        "MLC":"anotoly",
        "Frame":"True",
        "ImageUpload":"False"
    }
],
"Profile":
[
    { 
        "Title":"CLI",
        "File":"",
        "Profile":"H",
        "App":"AI.exe",
        "Location":"\\common\\Isolation", 
        "sensitivity":20  
        }


]
}
```

---

```
import json,os,sys
def testDataTransform():
source = 'C:/Users/WS/Downloads/Profile.json' 
Destination = 'D:/OL/SV/4.json'
datastore= None
with open(source, 'r') as content_file:
    content = content_file.read()



datastore = json.load(content)
```

This code is not working, any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: What is not working? Question is not clear...

Comment: I guess you have a problem with `json.load` as requires an open file object, not it's content. Try `with open(source, 'r') as content_file: datastore = json.load(content_file)`